# Template is missing error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

New to Ruby. Facing problem in transferring project from one pc to another.

> Missing template user/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Users/Mohit/RubymineProjects/BackChannel_v2/app/views"

The project runs fine on my other laptop. I just zipped all the files and transferred to my new laptop.

Run:

1. `update bundler` + `install bundler`
2. `rake db:create`
3. `rake db:migrate`

This is what i see on RubyMine.

```
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-02-12 14:48:26] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-02-12 14:48:26] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
[2014-02-12 14:48:26] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7964 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-12 14:48:27 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by UserController#home as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 198ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template user/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Users/Mohit/RubymineProjects/BackChannel_v2/app/views"
):
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:122:in `find'
  C:in `find_template'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:35:in `determine_template'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:8:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__821564139__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__934037464__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (20.0ms)
[2014-02-12 14:48:31] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Still unable to execute the project.

Comment: This not an issue regarding pc. if the commands that you have run for the database has been executed with success then project should be run.And make sure that you old pc and new pc configuration should be same regarding application which you are running.

Comment: It's telling you it's missing the template for the page you're trying to view, have you looked to see if that template is there?

Comment: could you add the full error backtrace.

Answer (score 1):

**Git**

You'd be **much** better using [git](http://git-scm.com/) to transfer the project

The error is telling you there is a specific view that's missing (`user/home`). Whether your code works or not, I believe the fact you zipped the project & tried to redeploy is partly to blame for the issue

I would highly recommend [setting up git with Rails](http://ruby.about.com/od/rails3tutorial/ss/Using-Git-With-Ruby-On-Rails.htm). This will help you put the project onto a shared repository ([GitHub](http://github.com)), where you'd have a central code base to work from

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please guide me through the steps for using Git with my rails application. I have already installed GIT

Comment: @Nick The project is running correctly in my old pc. So I dont think so there is any view missing. @ sachin edited the question.